# NO [UNAVAILABLE] FETCH Server error while fetching messages

Tags: jakarta-mail, fetch

Have anyone met this exception before? I cannot figure out what is the problem .

javax.mail.MessagingException: A415 NO [UNAVAILABLE] FETCH Server error while fetching messages;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A415 NO [UNAVAILABLE] FETCH Server error while fetching messages
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1268)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getReceivedDate(IMAPMessage.java:393)
    at eu.memshare.modules.mail.UserMail$3.match(**UserMail.java:805**)
    at javax.mail.Message.match(Message.java:705)
    at javax.mail.Folder.search(Folder.java:1270)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.search(IMAPFolder.java:1918)
    at javax.mail.Folder.search(Folder.java:1231)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.search(IMAPFolder.java:1873)
    at eu.memshare.modules.mail.UserMail.fetchMail(**UserMail.java:823**)
    at eu.memshare.modules.mail.UserMail.run(**UserMail.java:772**)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A415 NO [UNAVAILABLE] FETCH Server error while fetching messages
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:351)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1263)
    ... 9 more

This is the code where the exception is thrown:

```
SearchTerm term = new SearchTerm() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean match(Message message) {
                                try {

                                    if(message.isExpunged()){
                                        inbox.expunge();
                                       return false;
                                    }else if(message.getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.DELETED)) {
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    long min = Math.min(System.currentTimeMillis(), lastQueryDate.getTime());
                                    Date when = new Date(min);
                                    Date receivedDate = message.getReceivedDate();
                                    boolean after = when.before(receivedDate);

                                    if (all) {
                                        return true;
                                    } else if (after) {
                                        lastQueryDate = receivedDate;
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                                    return false;
                                }
                                return false;

                            }
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an error message from your server.  You'll need to check your server log files or contact your server vendor or provider to find out what's wrong.